# How do I do to search a value in a class?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, oop

I already have my different classes created but I need to create a function to find what the users introduce in my main class `Pais`.

The general idea is that the user introduce a date in a specific format and it need to find the values that happen in that date introduced.

```
from datosAPI import *
from Clima import *
from estado import *

class Pais:

    def __init__(self, name, capital, poblacion, area, moneda, lenguaje):
        self.name = name
        self.capital = capital
        self.poblacion = poblacion
        self.area = area
        self.moneda = moneda
        self.lenguaje = lenguaje
        self.lista_estados = []
        self.clima_list=[]
        def busqueda_por_fechas(self,date):
          oreo= False
          for datos in self.clima_list:
              if datos['date']== date:
                  print(f""Los valores climatologicos como resultado de la fecha introducida son: 
                    velocidad del viento  {datos['wind_speed']}
                    temperatura {datos['temperature']}
                    humedad {datos['humidity']}
                  oreo=True
          if oreo ==False:     
              print ("No se encontro nada")    
            
            
variables=[]
clima_list=[]    

   
for date in variables:
    clima_list.append(Pais(variables['temperatura'],variables['humidity'],variables['wind_speed']))
```